# Xrange chart height

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

How can I set the height of each bar in xrange charts? I don't want to specify the height of the whole chart, instead the height of each single bar.

This type of chart (as in the link):
http://jsfiddle.net/vqpjL3ns/1/

```
height of bar
```

Comment: do you want same height for all bars ?

Comment: @Ashu, I think he really want different height for each data in the same serie... I don't think that possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create separate series for each data point, than you will be able to set different width for each bar:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Project 1',
    pointWidth: 20,
    data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21),
        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
        y: 0,
        partialFill: 0.25
    }],
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
    }
}, {
    pointWidth: 15,
    data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
        y: 1
    }]
}, {
    pointWidth: 30,
    data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 8),
        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
        y: 2
    }]
}, {
    pointWidth: 40,
    data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 19),
        y: 1
    }]
}, {
    pointWidth: 10,
    data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 10),
        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 23),
        y: 2
    }]
}]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4uydm6tr/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.xrange.pointWidth